# Preload content before display for smoother experience?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gsap

My website https://www.dimovski.nu/ starts off with a scroll-triggered animation, displaying and updating a sequence of images on scroll. I have compressed the images as much as possible to optimize load time, but it's a total of 541 images.

Is it possible to preload all the images somehow? Should I have a loading page before the trigger animation in order to avoid a choppy experience?

Here's the JS code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const frameCount = 541;

const currentFrame = (index) => `./seq/${(index + 1).toString()}.jpg`;
const images = [];
let ball = {frame : 0};

for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
    images.push(img);
}

gsap.to(ball, {
    frame: frameCount - 1,
    snap: "frame",
    ease: "none",
    scrollTrigger: {
        scrub: true,
        pin: "canvas",
        end: "500%",
    },
    onUpdate: render,
})

images[0].onload = render;

function render(){

    context.canvas.width = images[0].width;
    context.canvas.height = images[0].height;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(images[ball.frame], 0, 0);
}
```

I have tried to find a solution of preloaders, but uncertain on which solution works best for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the number of request required to fetch these resources and the total size I wouldn't recommend doing this. Especially not on your landing page.

[image]

You could potentially reduce number of requests by baking all of the frames into one single image as i.e. sprite sheet and show a loading spinner, but the size, without any further compression, would be similar.

Another option could be to compile the frames into a video/animation, with better compression, and have an embedded video player rendering the frames based on scroll in the borderless player.